# Can I force the "hover" state to be refreshed with IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-sortable

In some corporate web application, I have some troubles with the `:hover` css selector with IE 8 users.

Basically, I have a lot of javascript, and the page sometimes is a bit slow.

Especially, my issue occurs in a `sortable` table (yes tables suck, but I have to live with it by now).

Within each row, I have a button that performs some operation. The button have `:hover` css rules to make it highlighted on mouse hover.

But in a specific case, the hover state remains, even if the mouse is no more on the element.

You can see the behavior on jsfiddle (run embbeded version with IE8): http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/K9EGv/24/embedded/result/

To reproduce the problem:

1. Start draging an element by clicking on the "hover" button.
2. very quickly, drop the item (even if the drag is not visually started) elsewhere in the list
3. still very quickly, move your mouse out of the table

The whole operation must be done under 1.5 second.

With this scenario, the initial dragged item is in the hover state, even if the mouse is no more on the button.

**Is there a way to "force" refresh of the hover state?**

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem, neither in IE9 in IE8 mode nor in a real IE8. Even if I do the drag & drop, which works fine, under one second.

Comment: actually, to reproduce the problem, you have to execute the whole mouse gesture before the jquery sortable start event handler is finished

Comment: I've uploaded a [video that shows the issue](http://www.hand-net.com/temp/repro3.m4v)